# Unbale to prevent PROPFIND http-method from servelt filter

Tags: servlet-filters

I have made a filter and register on web.xml 
when i am trying to filter http request of PROPFIND its throwing 500 Internal server error . this code works fine for any other http-methods. I want to have 405 in response code

```
if (httpRequest.getMethod()==”PROPFIND”) {
HttpServletResponse respProp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
respProp.sendError(405);
chain.doFilter(request, respProp);
} else {
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

error i am getting 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendError(ResponseFacade.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:120)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:673)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)

Answer (score 0):

```
Instead of sending error i have sent 405 as response and my problem got solved 

    if (httpRequest.getMethod()==”PROPFIND”) {
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;                              
    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
    } else {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```